# Group and Sum with dynamic column names

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I need to GROUP a table by Year and SUM all the possible Types (unknown) with dynamic column names.

Sample Table:

```
Type|Year
a    2001
a    2001
c    2002
b    2002
c    2003
a    2003
z    2003
```

Sample Result:

```
Year: 2001, Type_a: 2
Year: 2002, Type_c: 1, Type_b: 1
Year: 2003, Type_c: 1, Type_a: 1, Type_z: 1
```

Comment: I've tried basic IF statements, but I need to be able to handle an 'unknown' number of Types/Columns. ie:
"SELECT Year, SUM(IF(Type == 'a', 1, 0)) AS Type_a FROM Table GROUP BY Year" won't do it. I have seen some pivot examples, but they all deal with a 'known' number of variable Types/Columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group and sum types using a query like this -

```
SELECT year, type, COUNT(type) FROM table_name GROUP BY year, type;
```

It gives another result set, but with data you want.

Comment: I ended up following this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT year,COUNT(type) from tableName GROUP BY(type)
```

try that one

Comment: It's not dynamic columns names (AKA: pivot).

Answer (score 0):

SOL is not designed for that, the result could never have a various number of column for each line.

I think the best way to get that is to change the design of your resultset with concatenation of information by example. Or having fixed number of.column filled by null or empty values.

In the other hand you can do it programmaticaly if your language allows dynamic number of column for each row.